# labelColor not responding in Passbook coupon type pass

Tags: ios, passbook

All my Passbook environment works fine (PHP/MySQL based server for pass generation and signing, and the pass download - webview based download, emailing the pass or presenting inside my app with PassKit).

The only thing that is not working is the color of the labelColor in the primary fields of a coupon type pass.

I have (in the pass.json file):

```
"foregroundColor" : "rgb(30, 30, 30)",
"backgroundColor" : "rgb(230, 230, 230)",
"labelColor" : "rgb(30, 30, 30)",
```

The foregroundColor and backgroundColor work fine, but the labelColor (presented on top of the strip image) is white, instead of the labelColor specified.

According to Apple´s Passbook package reference, the labelColor is optional

"Optional. Color of the label text, specified as a CSS-style RGB triple. For example, rgb(255, 255, 255). If omitted, the label color is determined automatically."

In this case, the strip image is a clear image so, the text should be black (even if labelColor omitted and the color determined automatically), but the try appears white in the pass

Any help would be appreciated.

... e

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Label and foreground colors are only applied to primary field labels and values when there is no strip image in the pass.  Where a strip image exists, the text color is automatically changed to white.

There is an undocumented parameter `stripColor` that can be used to set the colour of the text over a strip image.  This changes both the field and the label.

This parameter has been around since the early iOS6 betas.  However, use with caution.  Just because it works today is no guarantee it will work in the future.

[image]

Comment: Thx @PassKit...  I added the stripColor parameter to the pass.json file, without the desired result. The text is always black...  (I am using a very dark fray: "stripColor" : "rgb(30, 30, 30)"  )
.  I tried  adding it in the main section and in the primaryFields section with the same result....   Am I doing something wrong?... rods.. enrique

Comment: It should be in the object root, the same as the other color keys.  If you can post a link to your pass then I can take a look.

Comment: Hi @PassKit..  this is the link to a working directory with the pass.json   [http://www.intergrapp.com/passbook/customerPasses/La%20Rua/source/pass.json]

Comment: When I click, there's nothing there (404). Also, the .pkpass bundle is better for debugging.

Comment: Hi @PassKit. A complete sample pass is locate here : http://www.intergrapp.com/passbook/customerPasses/La%20Rua/5334765b18407.pkpass  Thx in advance... e

Comment: Thx @PassKit. I got your example pass, but it still shows the text on top of the strip in white, instead of the black color specified in the stipColor within the pass.json file... Am I reading something wrong here?... thx... e

Comment: What version of iOS are you running - it appears black on my device. Have added picture to my answer.

Comment: This is weird.... The pass in your link r.pass.is/3dSDS5VIr6SR still shows the white text in my Mac OSX 10.9.2, but I checked it in PassBook (iOS 7.1) and it shows the stripColor correctly.  I guess that the stripColor parameter is working, but for some reason the pass preview in Mac is not taking it.... The good part is that it works in the device... Thx a lot.

Comment: Yes, the rendering in the Pass Viewer used by Safari and Mac Mail has always been quite a way off from what you'll see on a device.  Anyway, glad to hear it is working for you, but just remember there is no guarantee that this parameter will continue to work in future updates!

Comment: @PassKit really interesting, for my information, how do you find out undocumented parameters? any others interesting to share? Thxnk

Answer (score 3):

I found that using the "stripColor" does change the text in the strip outside of the "foregroundColor" parameter. This is still the case in iOS 8+

Here is example of where to put the "stripColor" in the json.

```
passJson = {
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass type goes here",
  "serialNumber": "serialNumber goes here",
  "teamIdentifier": "",
  "organizationName": "",
  "description": "",
  "logoText": "My Logo",
  "foregroundColor": "rgb(150,0,150)",
  "backgroundColor": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "labelColor": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
  "stripColor": "rgb(255,255,255)",
  "associatedStoreIdentifiers": [

  ],
  "associatedApps": [
    {
      "title": "Name of your app"
    }
  ],
  "barcode": {
    "message": "coupon",
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
    "altText": "coupon"
  },
  "coupon": {
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "offer",
        "label": "Offer text 2",
        "value": "Offer text 1"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
      {
        "label": "Expires",
        "value": "09/26/2015",
        "key": "expires"
      }
    ],
    "backFields": [
      {
        "label": "TERMS AND CONDITIONS",
        "value": "Back of pass",
        "key": "terms"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```